# Removing lingering end string after RewriteRule

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've tried everything but just can't seem to get things right :( I have over 800 urls and I need to rewrite them to point to a simple pdf file. Currently, I have links to:

```
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/?type=pdf&id=id123
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/?type=epub&id=id123
```

and I need this :

```
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/pdf/id123.pdf
http://subdomain.mydomain.com/epub/id123.epub
```

I've read through the htaccess and rewriterule Reference pages but I am still missing something. I can't remove the end string (?type=pdf&id=id123)

This is what I have :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^type=pdf&id=(.*)$ 
RewriteRule /?$ pdf/%1.pdf
```

And ofcourse it wrongly outputs:

```
 http://subdomain.mydomain.com/pdf/id1234.pdf?type=pdf&id=id123
```

I can't get rid of **?type=pdf&id=id123** at the end

Any help in the right direction would be fully appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding flag *query string discard* `[QSD]`:

```
RewriteRule /?$ pdf/%1.pdf [QSD]
```

Comment: Thank you but that doesn't seem to make a difference :(  I can't seem to get the redirect working via .htaccess locally - nothing happens

Comment: You should also be able to replace the query string by ending the replacement with `?` (an empty query string).To get some debug output for rewrite set the config to `LogLevel warn rewrite:trace8`.